# The C++ equivalent of Perl's Tie::IxHash (indexed associative array)?

Tags: c++, hash, containers, indexed

Perl's IxHash is an associative array that remembers the order in which elements were added to it, permitting you to directly (O(1)) access them either by key or by index .  It also has methods for returning all of the keys or the values, always in the order in which they were originally inserted.

Is there an equivalent container class for C++?

Comment: I don't know of any such container in the standard library. However, if you are willing to use Boost, you might find what you want in Boost's [Multi-Index library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Consider a composite of deque ( or array ) and an unordered_map.
If you need to delete, its gonna be O(n) (just like ixhash).
Iterating they keys is a dirty hack. If you want a real iterator for keys and values look at boost iterator_facade.

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <deque>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename KeyType, typename ValueType>
class MapWithInsertionOrder {
    public:
        bool exists(const KeyType &kk)
        {
            return cache_.find(kk) != cache_.end();
        }

        bool store(const KeyType &kk, const ValueType &vv)
        {
            if (exists(kk))
            {
                return false;
            }
            keys_.push_back(kk);
            cache_.insert(make_pair(kk, vv));

        }

        typedef unordered_map<KeyType,ValueType> cache_type;
        typedef typename cache_type::value_type value_type;

        typedef deque<KeyType> order_type;
        typedef typename order_type::iterator order_iterator;

        value_type &fetch(const KeyType &kk)
        {
            return *cache_.find(kk);
        }

        value_type &at(size_t idx)
        {
            auto kk = keys_.at(idx);
            return fetch(kk);
        }

        size_t size()
        {
            return keys_.size();
        }

        order_iterator keys_begin()
        {
            return keys_.begin();
        }

        order_iterator keys_end()
        {
            return keys_.end();
        }

    private:

        order_type keys_;
        cache_type cache_;

};

int main()
{
    MapWithInsertionOrder<string, string> mm;

    mm.store( "cat", "tom" );
    mm.store( "mouse", "jerry" );
    mm.store( "bird", "tweety" );
    mm.store( "dog", "spike" );

    cout << mm.at(0).second << endl;
    cout << mm.at(1).second << endl;
    cout << mm.at(2).second << endl;

    cout << mm.exists("cat") << endl;
    cout << mm.exists("mouse") << endl;
    cout << mm.exists("dog") << endl;

    for( auto itr = mm.keys_begin();itr != mm.keys_end();itr++ )
    {
        cout << *itr << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```